# Responsive Source Image in Angular 1 Way, Good or Bad?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

all. 
I am figure how to using a directive to using different source of image, but I am not sure is it good or bad. Can someone give me some suggestion? Here is my code
HTML

```
<img responsive-src 
    mobile="test1"  
    desktop="test2" />
```

JS Directive

```
app.directive('responsiveSrc',function($window, $timeout){

    return {
        restrict: "AEC",
        scope: {
            mobile: '=',
            desktop: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn){

            scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

            angular.element($window).on('resize load', function(){

                scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

                $timeout(function(){

                    if(scope.width >= 768){
                        element.attr('src', scope.desktop);                     
                    } else {

                        element.attr('src', scope.mobile);
                    }

                }, 300);


                // scope.$digest();
            })

        }

    }
});
```

JS Controller

```
  app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        $scope.test1 = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports";
        $scope.test2 = "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports";

    }]);
```

I saw some of the people using digest, but if I using resize the value will keep changing while the window is resizing so should I still using digest? And what it actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question that you have asked is a but vague but from what i have understood here goes.
scope.$digest() is used to manually trigger a digest cycle. Digest cycle in angular 1 is what is used by angular for firing watchers of a data model to check for changes in data since the previous digest cycle(In lay man's term, used to check for data changes). There are other angular directives that trigger the digest cycle. For example, $timeout that you have used in your code will trigger a digest cycle and hence, the code that you have written might work.
Also, We generally donot try to use scope.$digest but instead call scope.apply() which will inturn call the $rootScope.$digest() function.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you means. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `srcset` instead ... its supported natively by all browsers.

`<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="my alternate text">`

read more

> https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

`<img src="image-src.png" srcset="image-1x.png 1x, image-2x.png 2x,
                                 image-3x.png 3x, image-4x.png 4x">`

This will save your time, browser rendering unnecessary java-script.

Comment: :( but srcset is not supporting IE